# Animated icon: two classes HTML element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I start to build a blog at this [adress](https://blog.thetradinghall.com). I am a near n00b when it comes to HTMl and CSS, but I learn :-(

I have an issue with combining two classes for an icon. The icon is part of font-awsome, redirect to another page. I would like, if possible, make it animated **before** opening the new page.

I use [animated.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) to animate it. Just adding the two classes in my HTML does nothing, as it open directly the new page (in another tab).

Below is part of the HTML code:

```
<p class="social">
{% for title, link in SOCIAL %}
   <a href="{{ link }}" target="_blank">
       <i class="fa fa-{{ title }} fa-2x"></i>
   </a>
 {% endfor %}
 </p>
```

Below is part of css:

```
.social {
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 0px;
}
.social a {
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 15px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
color: #fff;
}

.links a {
font-size: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
font-family: sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
```

I have no idea how:

1. see the animation before redirecting to social page
2. where to place the class for animated icon. The class declaration will be for example:`class="animated infinite bounce"`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask you to rethink.

Don't annoy your users with an animation they need to see before getting to the info they are looking for, ... unless you are selling animated icons :)

Use `:hover` and `:active` to create an effect and leave the rest be.

*Update: Added a 2:nd version that persists after being clicked*

```css
.link {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background: silver;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:30px;
}

.link:hover {
    background: lime;
    /* 
      put your animation properties here...  
    */
}
.link:active {
    background: red;
    /* 
      ...or here...  
    */
}

.linker {
    display: none;
}
.linker:checked + a {
  background: yellow;
    /* 
      ...or here.
    */
}
```

```html
<a class="link">Click me!</a>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="linker"/>
  <a class="link">Click me 2!</a>
</label>
```

Comment: I will rethink and avoid animated when leaving the page. It is not worth. TY for the code I will test asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of some setTimeout chaining there is a simple solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/TGPtG/77/

```
$('#element').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#element').addClass('fadeOut');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#element').removeClass('fadeOut');
            $('#element').addClass('fadeIn');
            setTimeout(function() {
                alert('Here you can make redirect!');
            }, 1000); // time for fadeIn animation
        }, 1500); // time for fadeOut animation
    }, 0); // start fadeOut 
});
```